# Is there any way to subscribe to newPendingTransactions for PanCakeSwap with includeTransactions flag?

Tags: pending-transactions

I'm attempting to realtime-monitor PanCakeSwap swaps (so BSC blockchain).

I found this doc page: https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/HowTo/Interact/APIs/RPC-PubSub/

It cites an example:

```
{"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions", {"includeTransactions":true}]}
```

However every websocket connection I have tried ignores this flag.
And [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15804) seems to say the feature has been reverted (likely because of high network load).

Is support for this flag set at a blockchain level (i.e. it's impossible for PanCakeSwap) or implementation level (i.e. maybe some provider provides it)?

If the latter, does anyone know of a provider that provides it?

And if not, would I be able to accomplish this by running a Besu node locally?

My current approach is to subscribe without the flag, and inspect each transaction.
But this has crippling network load.

Comment: Any news regarding your question ? I have the same problem and right now the only solution I found is to use an endpoint node supporting GrahpQL instead of using eth_subscribe

Comment: You can do it with BlockNative